# Access and declare vueJs component inside other component slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-blade

I'm trying to declare and access an vue component inside a component slot.
The modal component will be creates several time and there it has to have an unique name but I don't no how I do that inside the slot.
using Laravel blade and vueJs

```
<template>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <slot name="head"/>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
            <slot name="line" v-bind:item="item" />
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

```
<list-component ref="teamMembers">
    <template v-slot:head>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email-address</th>
            <th>Role</th>
        </tr>
    </template>


    <template v-slot:line="slotProps">
        <td>
            @{{ slotProps.item.name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            @{{ slotProps.item.email }}
        </td>
        <td>
            @{{ slotProps.item.role }}
        </td>

        <td>
            <button @click="$refs.deleteItemModal@{{ slotProps.item.id }}">
                Delete
            </button>
        </td>

        <modal-component ref="deleteItemModal@{{ slotProps.item.id }}">
            
        </modal-component>
    </template>
</list-component>
```

How can declare and call modal component?

If I use it like this

```
<button @click="$refs.deleteItemModal">
```

and

```
ref="deleteItemModal"
```

it works but gives me always the same component.

Please advise me how I can create an unique ref to create something like this 'deleteItemModal' + slotProps.item.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
<modal-component :ref="'deleteItemModal' + slotProps.item.id">
</modal-component>
```

Static value should be covered with quotation mark and can use `+` to concat any dynamic value with the string like in javascript.

To call `openModal` method of that ref component, create method in `modal-component` component

```
deleteItem(itemId) { this.$refs['deleteItemModal' + itemId].openModal() }
```

and then change for button click event

```
<button @click="deleteItem(slotProps.item.id)">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how should I declare the click @click="'$refs.deleteItemModal' + slotProps.item.id + '.openModal()'" because this is not working.

Comment: You need to create an method and in that you can do the respective code you want as dynamic. and Call that method in click

Comment: The method is all ready there "openModal". But I'am unable to reference it.

Comment: Ok, but I mean to create method in `modal-component` component and call `openModal()` method of ref component in it. i.e. `deleteItem(itemId) { this.$refs['deleteItemModal' + itemId].openModal() }` and then change for button click event `<button @click="deleteItem(slotProps.item.id)">`

Comment: Thanks Urja, now I have it working.

Comment: @wiebe, I am thankful to help you to your issue. I edited my answer Can you please approve my answer?